# Homogenuous Sturm Liouville problem (condtion for negative eigenvalues)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

> Consider the Sturm - Liouville   problem:
>
> $$y''+\lambda y=0,$$ 
>   $$ y(0)=c\pi y'(\pi)-y(\pi)=0$$
>
> (a) Find the condition $c$ must satisfy, so that the problem has negative eigenvalues.
>
> (b) How many are the negative eigenlaues (in case they exist)?
>
> (c) For $c=1$, prove that $\displaystyle 1<\lambda_2-\lambda_1<\frac{9}{4}$, where $\lambda_1,~\lambda_2$ are the first two eigenvalues of the problem above.

*Attempt.* (a) $$\lambda \int y^2dx=-\int y''ydx=\ldots=\int(y')^2dx-c\pi (y'(\pi))^2,$$
therefore the condition $c$ must satisfy is 
$\int(y')^2dx<c\pi (y'(\pi))^2$ for all eigenfunctions $y$ (although I guess a condition should be independent of $\lambda,~y$).

(b) According to the theory, there are infinitely countably many (negative) eigenvalues.

(c)  I was thinking of the equation of $(i)$, but didn t get me anywhere.

Thank you!

Comment: The differential equation is the very classical harmonic oscillator differential equation with solutions $y=A \cos(t)+B\sin(t)$. You should begin by that !

Comment: I don't see how we get the solution you propose. Parameter $\lambda$ is unkwown and we are supposed to check the case where $\lambda=-k^2<0$, which lead to eigenfunctions of the form $A\sinh (kx)$ (since $y(0)=0$).

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to write $y=A \cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)$, in your case, it should be $y=A \sinh(kx=+B \cosh(kx)$. But the problem is that, with your strong constraint $y(0)=...=0$, I get an explicit value of $c$ which is $c=\tanh(\pi)/\pi$, and not an interval...

Comment: I meant $y=A\sinh(kx)+B\cosh(kx)$. I think it's necessary to begin by this. Don't you find the value $c=\tanh(\pi)/\pi$ like me ?

Answer (score 1):

Every non-trivial solution of $y''+\lambda y=0$ with $y(0)=0$ is a scalar multiple of the solution where $y(0)=0$, $y'(0)=1$, which has unique solution
$$
          f_{\lambda}(x) = \frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}x)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
(The solution at $\lambda=0$ is the limit of the above as $\lambda\rightarrow 0$, which is $f_0(x)=x$.)

Therefore, the eigenvalue equation with $c\pi y'(\pi)-y(\pi)$ and $y(0)=0$ has a non-trivial solution iff $\lambda$ satisfies the power series equation
$$
       0=c\pi f_{\lambda}'(\pi)-f_{\lambda}(\pi)= c\pi\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)-\frac{\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)}{\sqrt{\lambda}}.
$$
The equation where $\lambda=0$ is a limit of the above equation, which is
$$
            c\pi - \pi = 0 \implies c = 1.
$$
So $\lambda=0$ is a solution iff $c=1$. There is never such a solution where $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$, even if $c=0$, because that would require $\sin(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$ and $\cos(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=0$. Eliminating such cases gives an equivalent equation
$$
          \tan(\sqrt{\lambda}\pi)=c\sqrt{\lambda}\pi
$$
The only solutions $\lambda$ must be real because the Sturm-Liouville problem has only real eigenvalues $\lambda$.
There are infinitely many positive real values of $\sqrt{\lambda}$ satisfying the above, which is easily seen by overlaying the graphs of the two sides and looking for intersections. Nothing is gained by looking at the negative solutions $\sqrt{\lambda}$ because only the squares of the solutions determine $\lambda$. The negative values of $\lambda$ are determined by the imaginary solutions $\sqrt{\lambda}$, and only $\sqrt{\lambda}=i\rho$ for $\rho > 0$ need be considered because the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are squares of such $i\rho$ solutions. Substituting into the equation gives
$$
        \tan(i\pi\rho) = c\pi i\rho \\
              \tanh(\rho\pi)=c\pi\rho.
$$

Looking at the graph of $\tanh(\rho\pi)$ for $\rho > 0$, there can never be more than one solution of the above, and the borderline case is where $y=\tanh(\rho\pi)$ and $y=c\pi\rho$ are tangent at the origin, which is where
$$
     \pi = c\pi \implies c = 1.
$$
For $0 < c < 1$ there is exactly one positive solution $\rho$, which gives rise to one negative eigenvalue $\lambda=(i\rho)^2 = -\rho^2$. So there is a negative eigenvalue iff $0 < c < 1$, and there is only one in that case.